# Cross-Platform Screen Sharing / Viewing

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, screen-sharing

We have a small in-house development team and it would be useful if when one of the team is stuck on something to display it on a large TV screen mounted in the office for others to have a look at. Two of the developers are on Linux, the rest on Windows. The TV could plug into a small Linux system like a Raspberry Pi.

Basically I need a cross-platform (Windows and Linux) programme to allow people to share their screen or a specific window on, without the need to go down the whole remote desktop approach.

Comment: Is a free software a requirement of can it be commercial?

Comment: *or can it be commercial

Comment: Free - preferably in both senses of the term!

Comment: Just curious as to how that will help (also, what about contention, when there are two problems?).

Comment: Only one person would share their screen at a time, would be taken in turns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [ChromeCast](https://www.google.com/chromecast) to [cast your whole screen](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/07/26/tip-chromecast-can-cast-your-entire-desktop-screen-too-not-just-tabs/) as explained on [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/chromecast/answer/3228332?hl=en&ref_topic=4602553):

> With Windows laptops/desktops you can cast your desktop/laptop content (vs just the specific Chrome tab). Follow these instructions to start casting your system content:
>
> 1. In the top right corner of your Chrome browser, click the Cast icon Inactive cast extension .
> 2. Next to the where it says, “Cast this tab to …”, you’ll see a small dropdown. Click on that to change the source selection.
> 3. Choose “Cast this screen/window”
> 4. Choose the Chromecast device you want to cast to.
> 5. In the “Share your screen” dialog, choose “Entire screen.”
> 6. When active, the Cast icon will turn blue Inactive cast extension.
> 7. Enjoy your entertainment!

This option seems to be still in beta, and oficially it doesn't support Linux, but on [this thread](http://allaboutchromecast.com/chromecast-how-to-guide/how-to-use-chromecast-to-share-desktop-screen-and-audio-to-tv/) a post of January 2015 says:

> It works fine on my Ubuntu linux laptop, allthough no sound when I
>   cast the whole screen.

Comment: Thanks, I actually bought a Chromecast and am using this - works well on Arch Linux, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, and Windows, with no issues really! :)